# Get records per divisions from Loc_hist table by joining with area table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables called area and loc_hist.

In area table division list is present and in loc_hist division is combined with other 3 number and gives other details. 
INPUT

**Area**

```
div div_name 
11    ATALANTA 
14    Columbo
```

**Loc_Hist**

```
Item Loc  
0012 11378 
0013 11378 
0014 11378 
0015 14425
```

Here Loc is (first 2 digit of div+last 3 digit of other column).

**OUTPUT**

```
Div Count(records)
11   3
14   1
```

So here my question is how to take records from loc_hist table per divisions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle 11g sql developer

Answer (score 2):

And this is how you would do it in T-SQL

```
create table #area (div int, div_name nvarchar(20))
create table #Loc_hist (item nvarchar(10), Loc int)

insert into #area (div, div_name)
values
(11, 'ATALANTA'),
(14, 'Columbo')

insert into #loc_hist (Item, Loc)
values
('0012', 11378), 
('0013', 11378), 
('0014', 11378),
('0015', 14425) 

select ar.div, count(*) from #loc_hist lh
   join #area ar on LEFT(lh.loc,2) = ar.div
group by ar.div
```

Answer (score 2):

via: Oracle

```
   select t1.div,
          count(t2.Loc) as cnt
       from (select div,
              case when length(div)=2 
                   then div
                   when length(div)=3 
                   then substr(div,1,1)||substr(div,3,1)
                   else null end as dive
               from Area) t1
       left join Loc_hist t2
       on t1.dive = substr(t2.Loc,1,2)
    group by t1.div
```

now you can get it in both 3 digit div and 2 digit div.but you might got some problem if your div type is int or number or float.in that case you just convert the case when then part and it will be done

like this:

```
           (select div,
              case when length(div)=2 
                   then div
                   when length(div)=3 
                   then to_number(substr(div,1,1)||substr(div,3,1))
                   else null end as dive
               from Area) t1
```

or you can choose to do this part in the join condition using case when. but i'm not recommend that

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the response..I am using oracle DB. Oracle 11g sql developer. div is always present in loc. loc contains 2 kinds of criteria.  1st: if div is 2 digit in area table then loc is also same first 2 digit.  2nd: If div is 3 digit then loc excludes middle number and put it in loc as first 2 digit. Ex if div is 11 then loc is 11XXX and if div is 705 then loc is 75XXX. Kindly let me know if there is anyway to find out

Comment: Oh,there must be a way :) i ll update my answer to solve the 3 digit div thing, but i have to make sure if there is a 3rd case. the div only have 2 digit or 3 digit right?

Comment: done with the update hope this can help you @user3840800

Answer (score 2):

and this is how you do it in oracle

```
select a.div,count(*) from  area a 
inner join loc_hist b
on substr(a.div,1,2) = substr(b.loc,1,2)
group by a.div
```

Comment: Since loc_hist table contains huge data. query is not coming out.. Is there any way to do it chunk wise?